# iptables redirect from external interface to loopback's port?

Tags: linux, iptables

I try to redirect port from my lxc-container to loopback.

My lxc-container configured with lxcbr1 bridge 11.0.3.1.

I try to connect with netcat from host to lxc, and from lxc to host. Success.

localhost:

```
# nc -l 1088
```

lxc:

```
# nc 11.0.3.1 1088
Hello!
```

And localhost See message: "Hello!". Success!

When I redirect port that way:

```
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i lxcbr1 -p tcp -d 11.0.3.1 --dport 1088  -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:1088
# nc -l 127.0.0.1 1088
```

Thereafter, i try to connect from lxc-container:

```
# nc 11.0.3.1 1088
Hello !
```

But localhost doesn't see this message.

Where am i wrong?

I found this answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/211536/iptables-port-redirect-not-working-for-localhost

There sound words that loopback doesn't use PREROUTING. What should i do?

Comment: Isn't that prerouting rule just changing the IP address on the packet, and not to which interface the packet is sent?

Answer (score 6):

DNAT for loopback traffic is not possible.

I found alot of similar questions. [1](https://serverfault.com/questions/363899/iptables-dnat-from-loopback), [2](https://serverfault.com/questions/211536/iptables-port-redirect-not-working-for-localhost), [3](https://superuser.com/questions/594163/how-do-i-route-a-port-range-in-a-linux-host-to-a-guest-vm), etc...

According to RFC 5735, network 127.0.0.0/8 should not be routed outside host itself:

> 127.0.0.0/8 - This block is assigned for use as the Internet host loopback address. A datagram sent by a higher-level protocol to an
> address anywhere within this block loops back inside the host. This is
> ordinarily implemented using only 127.0.0.1/32 for loopback. As
> described in [RFC1122], Section 3.2.1.3, addresses within the entire
> 127.0.0.0/8 block do not legitimately appear on any network anywhere.

[RFC 1700](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1700), page 5, «Should never appear outside a host».

There is one of exits: use [inetd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inetd).

There are many inted servers, xinetd, etc.

My choice was rinetd.

I use this manual http://www.howtoforge.com/port-forwarding-with-rinetd-on-debian-etch

My config looks like this:

```
$ cat /etc/rinetd.conf 
# bindadress    bindport  connectaddress  connectport
11.0.3.1        1081            127.0.0.1       1081
11.0.3.1        1088            127.0.0.1       1088
```

I restart rinetd:

```
$ /etc/init.d/rinetd restart
Stopping internet redirection server: rinetd.
Starting internet redirection server: rinetd.
```

And redirection works like a charm.

I will not close this question by myself, cause I still in looking for more elegant solution for such task. It is unlikely to do this by any animal, netcat or inetd, it doesn't matter. This is my opinion.

Comment: thank you.  while trying to add a docker app to a bitnami host with preexisting LAMP stack, i was trying to redirect the docker app to the host's mysql server at 127.0.0.1:3306 to no avail.  this solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

Just for reference if someone stumbles upon here, on new kernel versions (probably >= 3.6), all you need to do extra is:

```
~# echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/route_localnet
```

**REFERENCE:** [ipv4: Add interface option to enable routing of 127.0.0.0/8](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/163683/)